# Change this with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use Jquery to get these classes **and change the font size**? Note that the tags keep changing numbers. I can also not edit the input.

```
<a class="tag-link-7" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Akira Kurosawa</a>
<a class="tag-link-8" title="1 topic" style="font-size: 8pt;">Ben Jones</a>
```

Comment: You should really be collecting these together using a class name, then using separate IDs for each - `<a class="tag-link" id="link-1" ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like `$('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('fontSize', '1.1em')` should do the trick. `a[class^="tag-link"]` selects all links [with their class starting with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) "tag-link".

Comment: so I would put it in a function like this? I couldn't get it to work  $(function () {
$('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('font-size', '1.1em');

Comment: Sorry, it should be `fontSize`, not `font-size`. My bad.

Comment: @Shadika is there a way to postpone the start of the function? For example, by default, all the tags load onto the page at a minimum size, and I want them to fade into this 1.1 em size.

Comment: Something along the lines of `$(document).ready(function() { $('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('fontSize', '1.1em'); })` should work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use attribute filters on class attribute

```
jQuery('a[class^="tag-link"]').css('fontSize',xx);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$("a[class^=tag-link]").css("fontSize",20);
```

Provided that your class "tag-link-*" comes first in the code. if not

```
$("a[class*=tag-link]").css("fontSize",20);
```

Note that `^` changed to `*`. Be sure to check this selector, as it may get you more that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use jquery's `.HasClass()` method to check if an element has a specific class